# Using a function to determine price

Tags: vb.net, vba

Not sure how to start this function or if I'm even doing it correctly, but I need to use a function that would determine the price of an item before any additional features are added.

```
Private Function WithoutCharge() As Double

    Return 150

End Function
```

Is what I currently have but it seems too easy. 150 Would be the number it returns or the price of the original item without any features added to it. Is that really all there is to it or am I just completely wrong?

Edit: Just realized I need 3 different prices/charges in this function. 150, 200, 300. How do I go about doing 3 different prices in one function or should I make 3 separate functions for it?

Comment: You can use one function and add an argument to it. But what is the criteria that you need to use to determine if it's 150, 200, 300?

Comment: Well the program includes radio buttons so would that be considered criteria? One radio button for each of the prices so if one is checked it could call for that price needed. How do I go about that?

Comment: `If radlow.Checked = True Then
    .....
   ElseIf
    ....
   End If`

Would something roughly like that work for which radio button is chosen to call for the correct price I would need?  After the ElseIf I would include the other buttons of course.

Comment: `vba` or `vb.net`? Significant difference, because `vb.net` uses return, and `vba` does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the return value to the name of your function - in your case, `WithoutCharge`.

```
Private Function WithoutCharge() As Double

    WithoutCharge = 150

End Function
```

But if you don't intend on doing any calculation to come up with that number, I wouldn't use a function at all, but instead use a constant.

```
Const WithoutCharge As Double = 150
```

---

Edit: In reponse to [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101965/using-a-function-to-determine-price?noredirect=1#comment85209327_49101965), you can certainly add an If statement to check for conditions in your function:

```
Private Function WithoutCharge() As Double

    If radlow.Checked Then
        WithoutCharge = 150
    ElseIf .... Then
        WithoutCharge = 200
    Else
        WithoutCharge = 300
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you but I just realized a mistake I made, there are three different charges/prices I need. 150, 200, 300. How would I go about adding those three to the function to call any of them when needed?

Also I need to use a function to determine original prices as per guidelines.

Comment: Perfect thank you, I didn't think it was that easy! With that I should be able to complete the rest of this work! Much appreciated.

Comment: Changing `Return 150` To `WithoutCharge = 150` will have no effect.